# Apache redirect problems with favicon on OpenClinica

Tags: apache, redirect, favicon

We have an [OpenClinica](https://www.openclinica.com/) system running on our webserver. It is configured to run on https://www.ourdomain.com/OpenClinica/ . Since our server is secured with SSL, we have also configured an Apache redirect to forward all http connections to the https version. It is of note that everything ran fine up until (seemingly) the most recent Firefox and Chrome updates. We have **not** changed any server configurations in the past few weeks that are likely to be an error source.

The new problem is that after logging into the system, any links that are clicked (show all study subjects, manage anything, ...) are *likely* to throw you out to the login page again. I say likely because there is no apparent pattern emerging - sometimes no links will be available without being thrown to the login page, sometimes a user can navigate two or three menus before being thrown out.

The behavior is also not consistent across browsers and computers (despite checking that all testing computers have the same browser versions): On my machine both of our servers do not work properly in Firefox and Chrome, but do work flawlessly in IE and Edge. On another machine, one system does not work on Firefox and Chrome (but does on IE and Edge), but the other one works across all browsers.

First off, here's the Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias www.ourdomain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.ourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.ourdomain.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/privateKey.pem

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /OpenClinica/favicon.ico https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/
    ProxyPassReverse /OpenClinica/favicon.ico https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/

    ProxyPass /OpenClinica/ https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/
    ProxyPassReverse /OpenClinica/ https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/

    ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/OpenClinica/

</VirtualHost>
```

I strongly think that there's a problem here. Let me explain the favicon redirect: When it is not present, all tested browsers will just display the favicon.ico file in their viewport upon login (or throw an error page if the favicon.ico is not present where expected). I realize that is not regular behavior and likely the root of the problem.

Below are the relevant access logs of my recent attempts. What I did was

- Login
- Click on "List all patients"

The system's reaction was to throw me out three times. On my last attempt the patient list was successfully displayed without me being redirected back to the landing page.

```
# Login
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:52 +0100] "POST /OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:52 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ HTTP/1.1" 200 200
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:52 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:52 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/MainMenu HTTP/1.1" 200 7860
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:53 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -

# Failed attempt
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:53 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ListStudySubjects HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:53 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login HTTP/1.1" 200 3656
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:54 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:54 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/RssReader HTTP/1.1" 200 618
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:54 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=3B4533DD528207EDE047FF5F03A67306 HTTP/1.1" 200 3656

# Login
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:55 +0100] "POST /OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:55 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ HTTP/1.1" 200 200
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:55 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:55 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/MainMenu HTTP/1.1" 200 7860
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:56 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -

# Failed attempt
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:56 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ListStudySubjects HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:56 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login HTTP/1.1" 200 3656
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:57 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:57 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/RssReader HTTP/1.1" 200 618
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:57 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=61B9ABF7FADA8BE010E7BA19B842D3D0 HTTP/1.1" 200 3656

# Login
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:58 +0100] "POST /OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:58 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ HTTP/1.1" 200 200
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:58 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:58 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/MainMenu HTTP/1.1" 200 7860
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:59 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -

# Failed attempt
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:59 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ListStudySubjects HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:24:59 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login HTTP/1.1" 200 3656
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:00 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:00 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/RssReader HTTP/1.1" 200 618
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:00 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/pages/login/login;jsessionid=7E5E5BAABF88A67655DF63968E8612A3 HTTP/1.1" 200 3656

# Login
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:01 +0100] "POST /OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:01 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ HTTP/1.1" 200 200
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:01 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:01 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/MainMenu HTTP/1.1" 200 7860
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:02 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/includes/new_cal/skins/aqua/theme.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1609
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:02 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -

# Successful attempt
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:03 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/ListStudySubjects HTTP/1.1" 200 17796
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2018:08:25:04 +0100] "GET /OpenClinica/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tomcat by default looks in the root-folder of the app for the favicon. In the case of OpenClinica it's not there, but in /OpenClinica/images/favicon.ico. You may want to copy it from there one level up.

Comment: Thank you. However what happens when the favicon is found is that the image file itself will be displayed in the browser (just as opening an image link, ie. http://www.my-page.com/image.jpg). I described that behavior shortly in my initial post.